# Header is not assigned value

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, mean-stack

this is my code

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Headers } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class DataproviderProvider {

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello DataproviderProvider Provider');
  }

  // registering the user
  resgisterData(registerdata) {
    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/contact',registerdata,{headers: headers})
    .map(res => res.json());

  }
}
```

I'm getting the error message like

> Argument of type '{ headers: Headers; }' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]:
>   string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.   Types of
>   property 'headers' are incompatible.
>       Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type 'HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
>         Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type '{ [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
>           Index signature is missing in type 'Headers'.

In visual studio code, it is displaying error at {headers: headers}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the type of the [HttpHeaders](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders) and not Headers.
This is what Type *'Headers' is not assignable to type 'HttpHeaders'* means.

You should something like this

```
let header = new HttpHeaders();
header.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

Comment: I'm getting a new error after correcting it. "Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object'." at .map(res => res.json());

Comment: This is because this HttpClient you are using already parse and returns a json. You probably was looking an old tutorial that used another HttpClient, that didn't do this. You can safely remove that .map( res => res.json() ). You can read this post that explains the differences: https://blog.angularindepth.com/the-new-angular-httpclient-api-9e5c85fe3361